# Android Espresso startActivity testing

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.login_email_textview)).perform(clearText(), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password_edittext)).perform(clearText(), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.login_email_textview)).perform(typeText(email), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.password_edittext)).perform(typeText(password), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.email_sign_in_button)).perform(click());
        intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), MainActivity.class)));
```

After the login button is pressed a Loading dialog shows up and Async task calls the server to check the credentials. After response the LoginActivity, witch I'm testing called finish() and MainActivity is started.

The test hangs after the login button is pressed. 
Also using:

```
@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);
```

Also in my code after I/m calling startActivity(), I'm calling finish() on the LoginActivity.

On sign_in_button I'm calling Volley request.

Comment: Use sleep to force the thread wait for response.

Comment: It works wit Thread.sleep(), but don't think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to fix your issue

I assume, that the `LoadingDialog` is showing an animated `ProgressBar`.

Using a `ProgressBar` and `Volley` together is actually not a bad idea. The `ProgressBar` will force `Espresso` to wait until `Volley` has finished its work in the background.

I assume, that your tests "hang" because you do not dismiss the `LoadingDialog`. So, to fix the issue, dismiss the `LoadingDialog` when you receive the response from `Volley`. But do not use `Espresso` to dismiss the `LoadingDialog`.

### More Information

There are "known issues" when using `ProgressBar` and `Volley` individually:

#### Issues with `ProgressBar`

If the `LoadingDialog` shows an animated `ProgressBar`, the animation blocks `Espresso`. The animation keeps the app's main thread busy and `Espresso` waits until it times out.

[See here for workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289152/progressbars-and-espresso/37864603#37864603)

#### Issues with `Volley`

`Espresso` does not know about `Volley`. If `Volley` executes requests in a background thread (I hope it does), `Espresso` does not wait, and your test will probably end before `Volley` returns a response.

An [`IdlingResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html) can be used to make `Espresso` wait for anything.

Comment: I'll implement custom IdlingResource to wait for the Volley request to finish.

Comment: I made Espresso wait with IdelingResource, but when it clicks to start the new activity it hangs. If I manually go back to the previous activity the test continues

Comment: Yes. Do you still have the ProgressDialog? And does it show a indeterminate ProgressBar?

Comment: No I removed it. I narrowed the problem to VolleyIdlingResource being lost after the transition to the second Activity.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution I came up with:

Custom IdlingResource:

```
public class VolleyIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
private static final String TAG = "VolleyIdlingResource";
private final String resourceName;

// written from main thread, read from any thread.
private volatile ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

private Field requests;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

public VolleyIdlingResource(String resourceName, Context context) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
    this.resourceName = checkNotNull(resourceName);

    requestQueue = MyApplication.get(context).getRequestQueue();

    requests = RequestQueue.class.getDeclaredField("requests");
    requests.setAccessible(true);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return resourceName;
}

@Override
public boolean isIdleNow() {
    try {
        Set<Request> set = (Set<Request>) requests.get(requestQueue);
        int count = set.size();
        if (set != null) {

            if (count == 0) {
                resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
            } else {
            }
            return count == 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
    this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
} 
}
```

And then in the test:

```
VolleyIdlingResource volleyResources;
        try {
            volleyResources = new VolleyIdlingResource("VolleyCalls", mActivityRule.getActivity());
            registerIdlingResources(volleyResources);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), MainActivity.class)));
```

Based on https://github.com/bolhoso/espresso-volley-tests/blob/master/EspressoTest/src/com/example/espressovolley/test/MyTest.java